# Using GLOB_RECURSE with add_jar

Tags: java, android, cmake, jar

How do I properly use `GLOB_RECURSE` with `add_jar` to specify wildcards? (Class name is `DestroyTesting`)
I'm trying to generate a jar using CMake.

My CmakeLists.txt

```
project(helloJavaNativeHeaders Java CXX)

cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.15)
# set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE 1)

include (CTest)
# set(TARGET_CREATE_JAR CreateJarPackage)
find_package(Java COMPONENTS Development)
include (UseJava)

file(GLOB_RECURSE javasources
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/testingthis/mytest/*.java
)

add_jar(DestroyTesting javasources)
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
...
[build] [1/1 100% :: 0.121] cmd.exe /C "cd /D D:\git\cmake\Tests\JavaNativeHeaders\out\build\Droid-x86-Debug\CMakeFiles\DestroyTesting.dir && "C:\Program Files\Android\jdk\microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25\bin\jar.exe" -cf D:/git/cmake/Tests/JavaNativeHeaders/out/build/Droid-x86-Debug/DestroyTesting.jar @java_class_filelist && "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -
...
[build] 'c' flag requires manifest or input files to be specified!
```

My java_class_filelist is indeed empty.

What does work is directly using:

```
add_jar(DestroyTesting ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/testingthis/mytest/DestroyTesting.java)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`file(GLOB_RECURSE)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/command/file.html#glob-recurse) command

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE javasources
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/testingthis/mytest/*.java
)
```

creates a variable `javasources` containing a list of your Java files. To access the **contents** of that variable, you must use the `${}` [variable reference](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/manual/cmake-language.7.html#variable-references) syntax:

```
add_jar(DestroyTesting ${javasources})
```

Comment: Hmm that worked but I didn't need it for the CPP related command :(